# check if written answer is matching the idea of answer

Tags: php

I'm writing a few pages with some mocks for training people, a kind of driving license test, but instead of picking the answer in my case, they have to write it.

obviously, the written answer won't match 100% of the answer and at the same time, each individual will have the answer in its own way.

how can this idea be achieved?

search engines don't come with positive results

Comment: A localllama can do this with okay accuracy, it wont be 100%.

Comment: Are they writing sentences, or just one or two words? The first will require NLP and maybe even more advanced AI. The second can use fuzzy matching to handle minor spelling mistakes.

Comment: I would say not more than 100-200 words

Comment: You'll need some decent AI, or a human